# How to continue writing command lines when terminal is hanging

Tags: linux

Right now, if I type in something that makes it so I am wanting for a response, I have to press ctrl + c to stop running and waiting. Is there a way to continue writing commands without pressing ctrl + c so I don't stop the program that is waiting?

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? Gnome terminal is notorious for this in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

You can add & to the end of your command line, and that command runs in the background, while you continue at the terminal.

Ex:

find . -name "*.pdf" > myPDFList.txt &

Answer (score 1):

You could [suspend the program by typing <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>](https://superuser.com/q/476873/14566) and then move the just-suspended process to background by entering the command

```
bg
```

You could then type more commands at the terminal prompt in the foreground while the other process continues to run in the background.